# (C++) Very Basic Questions Regarding Syntax

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, syntax

C++ novice here. I have some basic questions. In `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

1. How is `char *argv[]` supposed to be read (or spoken out to humans)?
2. Is it possible to clear/erase specific content(s), character(s) in this case, of such array? If yes, how?
3. Can arrays be resized? If yes, how?
4. How can I copy the entire content of `argv[]` to a single `std::string` variable?
5. Are there other ways of determining the number of **words** / **parameters** in `argv[]` without `argc`? If yes, how? (*)

I'd appreciate explanations (not code) for numbers 2-5. I'll figure out the code myself (I learn faster this way).

Thanks in advance.

**(*)** I know that `main(char *argv[])` is illegal. What I mean is whether there's at least a way that does not involve `argc`at all, like in the following expressions:

```
for( int i = 0; i < argc; ++i ) {
    std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
int i = 0;    
while( i < argc ) {
    std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    ++i;
}
```

Or

```
int i = 0;
do { 
     std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
     ++i; } while( i < argc );
```

Comment: it should be char* argv[], not char** argv[]. It's read as "argv is an array of pointers to char"

Comment: You mean `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's fixed now. Question #1 might no longer be valid. But I just leave there.

Comment: It's either `*argv[]` or `**argv` but not he mix you gave. Start by trying to find out what the exact difference is and why it matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** It is supposed to be `char **argv` or `char *argv[]` which is `a pointer to an array of characters` more commonly known as `an array of strings`

**2)** [CString](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/) is the std library to manipulate C strings (arrays of characters). You cannot resize an array without reallocating, but you can change the contents of elements by referencing it by index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
{
   //set all the strings to have a null character in the
   //first slot so all Cstring operations on this array, 
   //will consider it a null (empty) string
   argv[i] = 0;
}
```

**3)** Technically no, however they can be deleted then reallocated:

```
int *array = new int[15]; //array of size 15
delete[] array;
array = new int[50]; //array of size 50
```

**4)** This is one way:

```
string *myString;
if(argc > 0)
{
   myString = new string(argv[0]);
   for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
      myString->append(argv[i]);
}
```

**5)** Yes, according to Cubbi:

> POSIX specifies the final null pointer
>   for argv, see for example "The
>   application shall ensure that the last
>   member of this array is a null
>   pointer." at
>   [pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html)

Which means you can do:

```
char *val = NULL;
int i = 0;
do
{
   val = argv[i++]; //access argv[i], store it in val, then increment i
   //do something with val
} while(val != NULL); //loop until end of argv array
```

Comment: Actually it's not just POSIX, the C++ standard mandates that: "The value of argv[argc] shall be 0." in 3.6.1[basic.start.main]/2

Comment: Thanks. Even though I wish you didn't include codes. You've ruined the fun of cracking the puzzles of new language (new to me, btw). :)

Comment: @Corellis Sorry, I like to give examples in case what I say isn't clear, but I promise I didn't tell you everything that can be done to answer all your questions. There are many ways to solve different problems.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's an array of pointers to char.
2. Sort of - you can overwrite them.
3. Only by copying to a new array.
4. Write  a loop and append each argv[i] to a C++ string.
5. Most implementations terminate the array with a NULL pointer. I can't remember if this is standard or not.

Comment: strings are terminated with a NULL pointer, but arrays are not.

Comment: Nice typing speed! POSIX specifies the final null pointer for argv, see for example "The application shall ensure that the last member of this array is a null pointer." at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html

Comment: @Chad They are if someone (in this case the compiler implementors) puts a NULL in them.

Comment: @unapersson Obviously if someone puts one there, then there is one. What I am saying is you cannot assume there is one. (except in the case of argv)

Comment: Actually it's not just POSIX, the C++ standard mandates that too: "The value of argv[argc] shall be 0." in 3.6.1[basic.start.main]/2

Comment: @unapersson:  The C++ standard requires that `argv[argc]` be the null pointer.  You don't need to rely on POSIX for that, and you don't need to check compiler documentation (other than for their variances from the Standard).

Comment: @David, @Cubbi: yes, for `argv`, since the questions concern arrays in general (even though it uses `argv` as an example) it is worth noting that the `NULL` element is only worth for `argv`. For other arrays, it depends how they are filled, and they could contain several nulls elements or none.

Answer (score 1):

```
char **argv[]
```

Is wrong. It should be either `char **argv` or `char *argv[]`, not a mixture of both. And then it becomes a pointer-to-pointer to characters, or rather a pointer to c-strings, i.e., an array of c-strings. :) [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) is also quite helpful at thing like this.
Then, for the access, sure. Just, well, access it. :) `argv[0]` would be the first string, `argv[3]` would be the 4th string. But I totally wouldn't recommend replacing stuff in an array that isn't yours or that you know the internals of.
On array resize, since you're writing C++, use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), which does all the complicated allocation stuff for you and is really safe. Generally, it depends on the array type. Dynamically allocated arrays (`int* int_arr = new int[20]`) can, static arrays (`int int_arr[20]`) can't.
To copy everything in `argv` into a single `std::string`, loop through the array and append every c-string to your `std::string`. I wouldn't recommend that though, rather have a `std::vector<std::string>`, i.e., an array of `std::strings`, each holding one of the arguments.

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
for(int i=0; i < argc; ++i){
  args.push_back(argv[i]);
}
```

On your last point, since the standard demands `argv` to be terminated by a `NULL` pointer, it's quite easy.

```
int myargc = 0;
char** argv_copy = argv;
while(++argv_copy)
  ++myargc;
```

The `while(++argv_copy)` will first increment the pointer of the array, letting it point to the next element (e.g., after the first iteration it will point at c-string #2 (`argv[1]`)). After that, if the pointer evaluates to false (if it is `NULL`), then the loop brakes and you have your `myargc`. :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Too bad I'm not allowed to accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Several options: array of pointer to char OR array of C-string.
2. You can assign to particular characters to clear them, or you can shift the rest of the array forwards to "erase" characters/elements.
3. Normal C-style arrays cannot be resized. If you need a resizable array in C++ you should use `std::vector`.
4. You'll have to iterate over each of the items and append them to a string. This can be accomplished with C++ algorithms such as `copy` in conjunction with an `ostream_iterator` used on an `ostringstream`.
5. No. If there *was* such a way, there wouldn't be any need for `argc`. EDIT: Apparently for `argv` *only* the final element of the array is a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

1. `char *argv[]` can be read as: "an array of pointers to char"

   `char **argv` can be read as: "a pointer to a pointer to char"
2. Yes, you may modify the `argv` array.  For example, `argv[0][0] = 'H'` will modify the first character of the first parameter.  If by "erase/clear" you mean remove a character from the array and everything automatically shift over: there is no automatic way to do that - you will need to copy all the characters one-by-one over to the left (including the NULL termination)
3. No, arrays cannot be resized.  You will need to create a new one and copy the contents
4. How do you want to represent ALL the parameter strings as 1 std::string?  It would make more sense to copy it to an array of std::strings
5. No, there is no special indication of the last entry in the array.  you need to use `argc`

Comment: I like your answer to question no. 2. Wish SO allowed me to accept several answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is spoken as "array of pointers to pointers to character" (note that this is not the signature of the main function, which is either `int argc, char **argv` or `int argc, char *argv[]` -- which is equivalent).
2. The argv array is modifiable (lack of const). It is illegal to write beyond the end of one of the strings though or extend the array; if you need to extend a string, create a copy of it and store a pointer in the array; if you need to extend the array, create a copy of the array.
3. They cannot be resized per se, but reinterpreted as a smaller array (which sort of explains the answer to the last question).
4. You will be losing information this way -- argv is an array of arrays, because the individual arguments have already been separated for you. You could create a list of strings using `std::list<std::string> args(&argv[1], &argv[argc]);`.
5. Not really. Most systems have argv `NULL` terminated, but that is not a guarantee.

Answer (score -1):

Array in C/C++ is not an object, but just a pointer to first element of array, so you cannot simply delete or insert values.

Answering your questions:

1. `char *argv[]` can be read as 'array of pointers to `char`'
2. It's possible, but involves direct manipulations with data in memory, such as copying and/or moving bytes around.
3. No. But you may allocate new array and copy necesary data
4. By manually copying each element into `std::string` object
5. No.

As a summary: C++ is much more low-level language that you think.

Comment: There is no C/C++ language, although arrays are essentially the same in both C and C++.  In neither language is an array just a pointer, although they tend to decay into pointers on use.  In both C99 and C++, `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be the null pointer, so you can use that to tell the number of members of `argv`.  C++ has low-level elements, mostly taken from C, but modern C++ programs tend not to use them.